# Homeomorphism Between Finite Cartesian Product of Topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, solution-verification

I'd like to prove the following statement:

Let $X_{1}$,$X_{2}$,$X_{3}$ be topological spaces. Then $\left(\left(X_{1} \times X_{2}\right) \times X_{3}\right)$ is homeomorphic to $\left(X_{1} \times X_{2} \times X_{3}\right)$.

I considered the following function:

\begin{equation*}
f: \left(X_{1} \times X_{2}\right) \times X_{3} \to X_{1} \times X_{2} \times X_{3}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
f\left(\left(x_{1},x_{2}\right),x_{3}\right) = \left(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}\right)
\end{equation*}

and its inverse $g$

\begin{equation*}
g\left(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}\right) = \left(\left(x_{1},x_{2}\right),x_{3}\right)
\end{equation*}

and I want to prove that they are both continuos.

Let $U_{i}$ open in $X_{i}$ for $i=1,2,3$ and let $U_{1} \times U_{2} \times U_{3}$ a basis element for the product topology on $X_{1} \times X_{2} \times X_{3}$. Then the preimage of $U_{1} \times U_{2} \times U_{3}$:

\begin{equation*}
f^{-1}\left(U_{1} \times U_{2} \times U_{3}\right) = \left(U_{1}\times U_{2}\right) \times U_{3}
\end{equation*}
$\left(U_{1}\times U_{2}\right) \times U_{3}$ is open in the product topology on $\left(X_{1} \times X_{2}\right) \times X_{3}$. Then $f$ is continuos.

Conversely let $V\times U_{3}$ be a neighborhood of $\left(\left(x_{1},x_{2}\right),x_{3}\right)$  where $V = U_{1}\times U_{2}$ is open in $X_{1} \times X_{2}$ (since it is a basis element for the product topology on $X_{1}\times X_{2}$). Then $\left(\left(x_{1},x_{2}\right),x_{3}\right) \in \left(U_{1} \times U_{2}\right) \times U_{3}$.

\begin{equation*}
g^{-1}\left(\left(U_{1} \times U_{2}\right) \times U_{3}\right) = U_{1}\times U_{2} \times U_{3}
\end{equation*}
which is a neighborhood of $\left(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}\right)$.  Then I can conclude that $g$ is continuos.
Hence $f$ is an homeomorphism.

**Is it correct? Is there an easier proof?**

Comment: This is almost right. The concern might be that $g^{-1}(V \times U_3)$ might not be open even though $g^{-1}((U_1 \times U_2) \times U_3)$ is open where $U_1 \times U_2 \subset V$. You can fix this by taking advantage of that fact that since $V$ is open in the product topology on $X_1 \times X_2$, it must be a product of open sets, say $V_1 \times V_2$. With this small fix, your argument works.

Comment: @GaryD Thank you so much! By " $V$ must be the product of open set $V_{1} \times V_{2}$" you mean that $V$ is an element of the basis for the product topology on $X_{1}\times X_{2}$?

Comment: Well, not necessarily. The appropriate idea of a basis for $X_1 \times X_2$ would be the products of basis elements, i.e. if $B_1$ is a basis for $X_1$ and $B_2$ a basis for $X_2$, then it's clear that we can make a basis for the topology on the product by looking at products on the elements. What I was saying before is a bit more general: the definition of $V$ open in $X_1 \times X_2$ is that there are open sets $V_1 \subset X_1$ and $V_2\subset X_2$ such that $V=V_1\times V_2$. They don't have to be basis elements for $X_1$ or $X_2$, just open sets!